# PowerShell -match with -simplematch

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I have some code that is all working nicely

```
if ($myinput -match "$cmd") { $cmd = $cmd -replace "test", "output" }
```

Later on, I realised that I do not want the match to be a regular expression, but just a literal simplematch. i.e. I just want to find out if `$myinput` contains what is in the `$cmd` string (even if * . \ etc are in that string). Should I change `-match` to a different operator, or can I add a flag or modification here to just tell it to do a literal match?

Comment: You could leave it the same and just change `-match $cmd` to `-match [regex]::Escape($cmd)` provided you don't have special purposeful regex characters in `$cmd`.

Comment: You can also use `[wildcardpattern]::Escape($cmd)`. Then either surround `$cmd` with asterisks and use `-like` or just use `-eq`.

Comment: Fascinating. I've never seen this sort of thing before. Also maybe nice as I think `-match` is a lot faster than `-like` (I don't understand why, I would have thought that `-like` was simpler and hence faster, but various sites seem to show that `-match` is faster), so maybe I can just use -match for everything with this for literal matches! Testing now and works great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of a way to make `-match` work without regex, but there are a number of options you can use.

**Option 1: Escaping Regex Characters in `-match`**

If `$cmd` does not contain any special regex characters that you intend to be used as regex, you can simply escape the string. Even though you are still using regex, you are still searching for literal strings.

```
$cmd = [regex]::Escape('str*ng.txt')
$cmd
str\*ng\.txt

'string.txt' -match $cmd
False
'str*ng.txt' -match $cmd
True
'BEGIN str*ng.txtEND' -match $cmd
True
```

The behavior of `-match` is it will search an entire string for your match unless you use anchor characters.

---

**Option 2: Use `-eq` or `-like` With a Literal String**

If using `-eq`, you must expect an exact match. Your search string must literally match the target string, and substring matching does not exist. With `-like` you can still do substring matching, but wildcards will be needed.

```
# Testing with -eq
$cmd = 'str*ng.txt'
'string.txt' -eq $cmd
False
'str*ng.txt' -eq $cmd
True
'BEGINstr*ng.txt' -eq $cmd
False

# Testing with -like without escaping wildcards
$cmd = 'str*ng.txt'
'str*ng.txt' -like $cmd
True
'BEGINstr*ng.txt' -like $cmd
False

# Testing with -like while combining escaped wildcard chars and using wildcards
$cmd = [wildcardpattern]::Escape('str*ng.txt')
$cmd
str`*ng.txt
$cmd = "*{0}*" -f $cmd
$cmd
*str`*ng.txt*
'str*ng.txt' -like $cmd
True
'BEGINstr*ng.txt' -like $cmd
True
```

The behavior of `-eq` or `-like` requires you to either know the entire string or understand what wildcards to use to return the proper result.

---

**Option 3: Use Select-String**

[Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) supports the `-SimpleMatch` switch. This by default does substring matching of literal strings.

```
$cmd = 'str*ng.txt'
if ('string.txt' | Select-String -Pattern $cmd -SimpleMatch) {
    'Match Found'
} else {
    'Match not Found'
}
Match not Found

if ('str*ng.txt' | Select-String -Pattern $cmd -SimpleMatch) {
    'Match Found'
} else {
    'Match not Found'
}
Match Found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8).  Note that it is case sensitive with one argument.  $input is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1) in powershell.

```
if ($myinput.contains("$cmd")) { $cmd = $cmd -replace "test", "output" }
```

Comment: ah, my bad, I changed the odd name of the variable in my actual code to something I thought more generic, `$input` was a bad choice! I've updated the OP to $myinput to avoid confusion. So that's interesting. I see that you are not using the PowerShell `-contains` operator (which is specifically for collections!) and instead using the .NET `.contains()`. That's also a very interesting approach that I had not considered. I will make use of this also in future for certain. All very useful thanks.